# Visual Studio 2022 Razor Mis-behaviour

Tags: c#, blazor, visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know how to turn off these notifications?

[image]

Visual Studio 2022 with Net6?  Clear them and click/move somewhere else on the page and they re-appear.  They appear to be linked to the totally arbitrary Intellisense behaviour in Blazor Razor components.

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a bug report to Microsoft than a question to the community.

Comment: There's not a lot we can do to help. Have a look at the stack trace, that might help, otherwise as @gunr2171 says, report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, the main question though is "Does anyone know how to turn these notifications off?" which I think is a valid question.

Comment: You can't stop them, have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: Several times, they go away for a while and then start again.  They seem to be related to the very slow responses I've seen to edit changes in Blazor Razor pages.  And before you ask this is a new machine with plenty of oomph!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issues have disappeared with the latest updates to VS 2022.